# In jQuery, what is selected with $('<div />', {text : $this.attr('title')})?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

well, I'm quite new to jQuery and while browsing all the documentation I found a [tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) on jQuery site about developing plugins. While reading it and trying to understand, I found something I can't find answer for. The example in section [6.3 Data](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Data) has such code in it:

```
var $this = $(this),
         data = $this.data('tooltip'),
         tooltip = $('<div />', {
           text : $this.attr('title')
         });
```

I understand that it is declaration of several variables on one line, however, the last one - tooltip - is the one I'm interested in. Can someone be patient with my ignorance and explain me what will be the content of tooltip variable after processing that line?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It creates a new div element, and passes the value of `$this.attr('title')` to jQuery.fn.text

More information: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

> jQuery( html, props )
>
> html: A string defining a single, standalone, HTML element (e.g.  or ).
>
> props: An map of attributes, events, and methods to call on the newly-created element.

and

> As of jQuery 1.4, the second argument can accept a map consisting of a superset of the properties that can be passed to the .attr() method. Furthermore, any event type can be passed in, and the following jQuery methods can be called: val, css, html, text, data, width, height, or offset.

Comment: Could have been done like this too: tooltip = $('<div>' + $this.attr('title') + '</div>')

Comment: @Capsule, what if the title has a value `</div>`?

Comment: Short, exact and complete answer. I like such. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think that

```
tooltip = $('<div />', {
           text : $this.attr('title')
         });
```

is equivalent to :

```
tooltip = $('<div />').text( $this.attr('title') );
```

If u're running under Firefox or chrome, you may be try console.log( ..any.. ). It's very helpful to see precisely a variable